# Using an external global variable file that is not bundled

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I have a JS file that I use for internationalisation. I want to be able to pass this JS file to a client for them to edit without the need for me to rebuild the entire project.

Currently I keep this file in the static folder so it gets carried over to my dist folder post build (I am using the vue-cli-webpack template).

translation.js

```
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      welcome: 'Welcome',
    },
  },
  fr: {
    message: {
      welcome: 'Bonjour',
    },
  },
};

export default messages;
```

I import this in my main.js as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import App from './App';

import messages from '../static/translation';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en', // set locale
  messages, // set locale messages
});

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  i18n,
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
});
```

While in my dev environment this works exactly how I want with hot reloading (Change a string in translation.js and it updates my application) but once I have built the application and put it on a production site it will no longer hot reload.

How can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I achieved the desired outcome:

Inside my Index.html I include the following static js file:

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="/static/translation.js"></script>
  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>
```

The translation.js file is as follows:

```
const messages = {
  en: {
    title: {
      test_page: 'Test Page Title',
    },
  },
};

window.messages = messages;
```

main.js is changed as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import App from './App';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en', // set locale
  messages: window.messages, // set locale messages
});

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  i18n,
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
});
```

This allows me to use this globally as so:

```
<template>
  <div class="test-parent">
    <h1>{{ $t('title.test_page') }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

And any changes I make to the translation.js file are shown in the production environment.